Return derived class from the base class
We are developing an internal NuGet package which contains a ServiceRes and ServiceRes<T> classes which can be used to wrap a response from the service layer into a common structure. This is the code that we have currently:
public class ServiceRes
{
    protected internal ServiceRes() { }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    public string? Message { get; set; }

    public static ServiceRes Success()
    {
        return Success(message: null);
    }

    public static ServiceRes Success(string? message)
    {
        return new ServiceRes
        {
            IsSuccess = true,
            Message = message
        };
    }

    public static ServiceRes MapFrom<TPrev>(ServiceRes<TPrev> othr)
        where TPrev : class
    {
        return new ServiceRes
        {
            IsSuccess = othr.IsSuccess,
            Message = othr.Message
        };
    }
}

public class ServiceRes<T> : ServiceRes where T : class
{
    protected internal ServiceRes() { }

    public T? ResponseObj { get; set; }

    public static ServiceRes<T> Success(T responseObj)
    {
        return new ServiceRes<T>
        {
            IsSuccess = true,
            Message = null,
            ResponseObj = responseObj
        };
    }

    public static new ServiceRes<T> MapFrom<TPrev>(ServiceRes<TPrev> othr)
        where TPrev : class
    {
        return MapFrom(othr, null);
    }

    public static ServiceRes<T> MapFrom<TPrev>(ServiceRes<TPrev> othr, Func<TPrev?, T?>? responseObjMapper)
        where TPrev : class
    {
        return new ServiceRes<T>
        {
            IsSuccess = othr.IsSuccess,
            Message = othr.Message,
            ResponseObj = responseObjMapper?.Invoke(othr.ResponseObj)
        };
    }
}

We have a .NET Core web application project which references our private NuGet package. We can use it like this:
public class ServiceResTest
{
    private class Obj1
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    private class Obj2
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
    
    public void Test()
    {
        // base usage
        var x1 = ServiceRes.Success();
        var x2 = ServiceRes.Success(message: "User created successfully");
        var x3 = ServiceRes<Obj1>.Success(new Obj1());

        // mapping
        var x4 = ServiceRes.MapFrom(x3); // ServiceResult<Obj1> -> ServiceResult
        var x5 = ServiceRes<Obj2>.MapFrom(x3); // ServiceResult<Obj1> -> ServiceResult<Obj2> (ResponseObj = null)
        var x6 = ServiceRes<Obj2>.MapFrom(x3, x => new Obj2() // ServiceResult<Obj1> -> ServiceResult<Obj2>
        {
            Value = $"{x?.Name}_value"
        }); 
    }
}

However, we have some advanced use-cases in our web application which require extending BaseService<T> class. We would like to be able to map ServiceResult<T> to ServiceResultExt<T>, preferrably in the similar fashion than existing MapFrom methods. Comments below indicate where the process fails.
public class ServiceResExt<T> : ServiceRes<T> where T : class
{
    public int FailedLoginsCount { get; set; }

    public static ServiceResExt<T> SuccessExt(T responseObj, int failedLoginsCount)
    {
        var baseRes = ServiceRes<T>.Success(responseObj);
        // map ServiceRes<T> to ServiceResExt<T>
        var x1 = ServiceResExt<T>.MapFrom(baseRes); // x1 is of type ServiceRes<T>
        // we would like to assing parameter failedLoginsCount to property FailedLoginsCount 
        x1.FailedLoginsCount = failedLoginsCount;
        return x1;
    }
}

What would be the best approach to handle cases where we have a class which extends ServiceRes<T> (ex. ServiceResExt<T>) and we would like to utilize existing methods (ex. Success), but map the response to ServiceResExt<T>? Can the mapping logic for derived classes be placed inside ServiceRes<T> class so it is common for all classes which inherit from it (we don't want anyone manually instantiating ServiceRes class, hence the protected internal constructor)? Can ServiceRes<T> return an instance of the derived class?

You could use a protected virtual method to create the correct object type when mapping.
I would write this something like:
public class ServiceRes
{
    protected ServiceRes(bool isSuccess, string message) 
        => ( IsSuccess, Message ) = ( isSuccess, message );

    public static ServiceRes Success => new (true, "");
    public static ServiceRes Fail(string message) => new(false, message);
    public bool IsSuccess { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
}

public class ServiceRes<T> : ServiceRes
    where T : class
{
    private readonly T responseObj;
    protected ServiceRes(T response, bool isSuccess, string message) : base(isSuccess, message)
        => responseObj = response;
    protected virtual ServiceRes<T2> Create<T2>(T2 v) where T2 : class => new(v, IsSuccess, Message);

    public T Response => IsSuccess ? responseObj : throw new InvalidOperationException();
    public new static ServiceRes<T> Success(T response)  => new(response, true,  "");
    public new static ServiceRes<T> Fail(string message) => new(null, false,message);
    public ServiceRes<T2> MapFrom<T2>(Func<T, T2> select) where T2 : class 
        => IsSuccess ? Create(select(Response)) : Create<T2>(null);
}

public class ServiceResExt<T> : ServiceRes<T>
    where T : class
{
    protected ServiceResExt(T value, bool isSuccess, string message, int failedLoginsCount) : base(value, isSuccess, message) 
        => FailedLoginsCount = failedLoginsCount;
    protected virtual ServiceResExt<T2> CreateExt<T2>(T2 v) where T2 : class
        => new(v, IsSuccess, Message, FailedLoginsCount);
    protected override ServiceRes<T2> Create<T2>(T2 v) => CreateExt(v);

    public int FailedLoginsCount { get; }
    public new static ServiceResExt<T> Success(T response, int failedLoginsCount) => new(response, true, "", failedLoginsCount);
    public new static ServiceResExt<T> Fail(string message, int failedLoginsCount) => new(null, false, message, failedLoginsCount);
    public new ServiceResExt<T2> MapFrom<T2>(Func<T, T2> select) where T2 : class 
        => IsSuccess ? CreateExt(select(Response)) : CreateExt<T2>(null);
}

It makes no sense to map the ServiceRes base class, so it lacks any such methods.
And I'm not sure it reaches your goal of having the mapping logic in the base ServiceRes<T>. But that should not be that much logic, and you could replace ServiceResExt.MapFrom with (ServiceResExt<T2>)base.MapFrom(select), even if that would be somewhat less safe if further extensions are added.
But it should keep the same outer type before and after the mapping, regardless of the type of reference. And also return the same outer type of reference due to the hiding of the MapFrom method.
You might also need to add back some ?, I wrote this without nullable reference types. I would recommend to make these classes immutable, having public setters seem weird, and dangerous.
